# bootstrapped l2,1 least square does not produce sparse solution

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection, model-selection, sparse

I am trying to model an autoregressive model with $\ell$-2,1 regularization, where $\|X\|_{2,1}=\sum_i|\sum_jX_{ij}|$:
$$y_{t+1} = wx_{t} + \lambda_1\|w\|_{2,1}, y\in \mathbb{R}^{n_1}, x\in \mathbb{R}^{n_2}, w\in \mathbb{R}^{n_1 \times n_2}, n_2\gg n_1, t\in\{1,\dots,T\},T=150, n_2\gg T$$

I call the vector $x$ a feature vector, hence I have $n_2$ features. I divided the data into $80\%,10\%,10\%$ training, validating, and testing. I used Bootstrapped lasso to select the most important features. I select feature $i$ if there is at least one nonzero element in the column $i$ of the estimated matrix $w$. I have 20 bootstrapped samples, where each one of them is generated by applying Block Bootstrap with a block size of 10. For each regularization parameter $\lambda_{1}$, the intersection of the selected features is chosen and then the selected features are re-estimated using least square method. The regularization parameter that gives the lowest validation error is chosen.

I noticed that the intersection for regularization parameters that give a sparse solution is empty (i.e., no parameter is selected). So, the solution always gives non-sparse solution. Do you see a problem in my analysis? If not, what conclusion can I make based on such results? Does that mean the optimal solution is not sparse?

Comment: I am interested to know why a $21$-norm is being used here.

Comment: @DifferentialPleiometry Using 1-norm will not necessary select features but will create a sparse matrix. Imagine that the solution is a diagonal matrix, which is a sparse matrix but it includes all the features. 21-however poses a sparsity pattern that "zero-out" some features.

Comment: By definition, the $L^{21}$ norm of $w=(w_1,\ldots,w_n)$ is $||w||_{21}=(|w_1|^{21} + \cdots + |w_n|^{21})^{1/21}.$  I doubt that's what you mean.

Comment: @whuber Correct. I meant $\ell$-2,1

Comment: Yes, but please don't leave the interpretation of your notation to chance: in your post, explain what it means.  That's what @DifferentialPleiometry was hinting at.